# Find the vector indices of the unique element

Tags: r, vector

```
set.seed(2)
vec <- sample(seq(3), 10, replace=T)
inverse_indices <- c(1,2,3,1,2,2,1,2,3,3)
identical(unique(vec)[inverse_indices], vec) #True
```

In `np.unique` if we set `return_inverse` to `True`, we can get the indices of the unique array that can be used to reconstruct the array.

How can I get the `inverse_indices` in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is `match` with the `unique` values of 'vec'

```
new_indices <- match(vec, unique(vec))
all.equal(new_indices, inverse_indices)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is convert to `factor` and then coerce it to `integer`

```
as.integer(factor(vec, levels = unique(vec)))
```